# ¿Como agrego AFC a un grid de productos woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy usando el plugin ACF en un sitio web wordpress con woocommerce, pero ahora tengo el problema que necesito mostrar tres precios diferentes en la parrilla de productos, como muchos sabes este modulo no tiene ese tipo de ediciones

Alguien sabe una forma de insertar un campo personalizado dentro de cada caja de producto mostrado en la parrilla de woocommerce?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: En un lado usas AFC y en otra ACF, y lo peor es que ni siquiera dices que es eso. Pon un mejor contexto y seguro alguien te ayuda. Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].